# SQL Server: how to convert SAP-style CALWEEK to CALMONTH?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2014, sap-data-dictionary

The year 2015 has 53 weeks while the year 2016 has 52 weeks. Hence, the CALMONTH cannot be calculated by the week number divided by four and then ceiling it. CALWEEK is reported such as `201652`, `201501` and `201104`. CALMONTH is a number between a range `%YEAR%MONTH`such as `201501` and `201512` for the year 2015.

How can I convert the SAP-style CALWEEK to CALMONTH in SQL Server 2014?

**EDIT** (from OP comments):

> *"I have data with SAP fields to be edited in SQL Server. I need to convert CALWEEK to CALMONTH. The beginning data comes with CALMONTH and CALWEEK fields so I could try to do some JOIN to get back from WEEKs to MONTHs. I always do casting because every field is in VARCHAR even though CALMONTHs/CALWEEKs"*

Comment: What do you actually need? You can't convert weeks to months, because it can be 1 or 2 months. Please add a proper example instead of just referring to SAP functions.

Comment: @JamesZ what? I have data with SAP fields to be edited in SQL Server. I need to convert CALWEEK to CALMONTH. The beginning data comes with CALMONTH and CALWEEK fields so I could try to do some JOIN to get back from WEEKs to MONTHs.

Comment: What datatype is it stored as?

Comment: @Jason I always do casting because every field is in varcher even though CALMONTHs/CALWEEKs.

Comment: Still no idea about what you're trying to do. Weeks do not match months, so you can't just convert a week into a month without giving more details. Do you use Monday? Wednesday? Sunday? Why don't you give concrete examples about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm crazy, but I thought this was kind of fun to figure out. I had to tear the string apart and get the date of the first day of the week. Then figured out the month and pieced it back to a string

```
CREATE TABLE #f(
  CALWEEK VARCHAR(10));

INSERT #f (CALWEEK)
VALUES ('201602'),('201606'),('201612'),('201624'),('201630'),
   ('201632'),('201650'),('201652'),('201701'),('201706'),('201715');


SELECT CALWEEK,
    --GETTING THE YEAR
    CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,6,'1/1/' + 
    SUBSTRING(CALWEEK,1,4)) +
    (SUBSTRING(CALWEEK,5,6)-1), 6))AS VARCHAR(4))+
    --GETTING THE MONTH
    CASE WHEN LEN(
    CAST(DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,6,'1/1/' + 
    SUBSTRING(CALWEEK,1,4)) +
    (SUBSTRING(CALWEEK,5,6)-1), 6)) AS VARCHAR(2))) = 1 
    THEN '0' + CAST(DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,6,'1/1/' + 
    SUBSTRING(CALWEEK,1,4)) +
    (SUBSTRING(CALWEEK,5,6)-1), 6)) AS VARCHAR(2))
    ELSE CAST(DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,6,'1/1/' + 
    SUBSTRING(CALWEEK,1,4)) +
    (SUBSTRING(CALWEEK,5,6)-1), 6)) AS VARCHAR(2)) END AS 'CALMONTH'
FROM #f

DROP TABLE #f
```